# Try, catch, except in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, try-catch

I'm looking to calculate certain ratios in this bit of code and put the result in a DataFrame. Since the statements that I'm scraping aren't uniform, some variables may be missing and cause KeyErrors or TypeErrors. What I am looking to do is only replace the location where the error happens with "Error."

The way I've currently coded it results in the whole row displaying "Error."

Here is my code:

```
try:
    Ratio_df.loc[stock] = [stock, beta, dividendYield, (sharesOutstanding*close_price_num)/1000000000,
                           '{:.2f}'.format(close_price_num), (close_price_num/earnings/1000),
                           (EV/(final_df.at['Total Revenue', 'ttm'])/1000), close_price_num/EE, EV/RE,
                           float('{:.1f}'.format((RE/(final_df.at['Total Revenue', 'last year']*1000) - 1)*100)), EV/final_df.at['Normalized EBITDA', 'ttm']/1000,
                           EV/1000000000, '{:.1f}'.format((FCF/(final_df.at['Total Revenue', 'ttm'])/10)),
                           '{:.1f}'.format(final_df.at['Normalized EBITDA', 'ttm']/final_df.at['Total Revenue', 'ttm']*100),
                           (EV/(final_df.at['Normalized EBITDA', 'last year'] * (1 + (RE/(final_df.at['Total Revenue', 'last year']) - 1)))), '-']
except KeyError:
        Ratio_df.loc[stock] = 'Error'
```

Here is the result:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQoNd.png)

Thank you for your help! Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of text. Use the `df.to_clipboard()` method to get a pasteable text version of your dataframe. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the way it is currently written you are aborting the whole row calculation on the first error, so even if you did know the position of the error, you couldn't proceed with the next computations. Instead, you can wrap each calculation with a `try-catch`, placing g an `"Error"` string if an error has occurred. It is also best to wrap it with a function. I created a toy dataset for example because reproducing from your question was impossible:

```py
from typing import Callable, Union

def compute_or_error(action: Callable) -> Union[float, str]:
    try:
        return action()
    except KeyError:
        return "Error"


df = pd.DataFrame({"A": list(range(3)), "B": list(range(1, 4))})
i = 0
df.loc[i] = [compute_or_error(lambda: df["B"][i] / df["C"][i]), df["B"][i] + df["A"][i]]
print(df)
```

The result is as follows:

```
       A  B
0  Error  1
1      1  2
2      2  3
```

After modifying your code it would look something like that:

```py
Ratio_df.loc[stock] = [
    stock,
    beta,
    dividendYield,
    compute_or_error(lambda: (sharesOutstanding * close_price_num) / 1000000000),
    compute_or_error(lambda: round(close_price_num, 2)),
    compute_or_error(lambda: close_price_num / earnings / 1000),
    compute_or_error(lambda: EV / (final_df.at['Total Revenue', 'ttm']) / 1000),
    compute_or_error(lambda: close_price_num / EE),
    compute_or_error(lambda: EV / RE),
    compute_or_error(lambda: round((RE / (final_df.at['Total Revenue', 'last year'] * 1000) - 1) * 100, 1)),
    compute_or_error(lambda: EV / final_df.at['Normalized EBITDA', 'ttm'] / 1000),
    compute_or_error(lambda: EV / 1000000000),
    compute_or_error(lambda: round(FCF / (final_df.at['Total Revenue', 'ttm']) / 10, 1)),
    compute_or_error(
        lambda: round(final_df.at['Normalized EBITDA', 'ttm'] / final_df.at['Total Revenue', 'ttm'] * 100, 1)),
    compute_or_error(lambda: EV / (final_df.at['Normalized EBITDA', 'last year'] * (
            1 + (RE / (final_df.at['Total Revenue', 'last year']) - 1)))),
    '-']
```

You didn't provide the original dataset to check the solution, but it should work

Comment: I was hoping there was an alternative to iterating through every field. Oh well, thank you so much for the clarification. I know my code isn't the cleanest, I'm still learning the most efficient ways to do things.

Much appreciated!